# IndexRoute showing same page for every path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have written this routes.jsx file using `IndexRoute`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, IndexRoute} from "react-router";

import {Default } from "./default";
import Home from "./home";
import Login from "./login";

export const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={Default}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  </Route>

);
```

When I open my app at 3000 port `Home` is showing but when I do `/login` still it is rendering `Home`.Anything I am doing wrong with this configuration?

Comment: Which version of react-router are you using and are you getting any error in console. Also can you add the code for default

Comment: I am not getting any error in console.react-router version is 2.8.1.

Comment: Is  the url changing and are what history object you are using

Comment: url is not changing and I am not using history object

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '/' before login.

`<Route path="login" component={Login} />`

Because it is taking the '/' from parent Route.